# Detect new tab is active and run button timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Hey i have a faucet site . i create a iframe (using 'iframeTracker-jquery-master') when anyone click the iframe open ad in new tab and showing the "claim" button . but i am trying the claim button wait for 20sc after click the iframe and if new tab is opening . If user close the new tab before 20sc then disable the button need again reload the page .

**Js Code detect iframe click**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // iframe
    $('.adbit-display-ad').iframeTracker({
        blurCallback: function(){
            $('<div class="consoleDebug">').html('<input type="submit" id="get" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Get!">').appendTo('#consoleDebug').delay(3000);
        }
    });
});
```

Just i can detect window is active or not by this code

```
$.windowActive = true;

$.isWindowActive = function () {
    return $.windowActive;
};

$(window).focus(function() {
    $.windowActive = true;
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    $.windowActive = false;
});
```

Now how can add this code with the button ? This code only detect user is here or not but how can i detect from my site the new tab is active and then run this button timer

```
function startTimer(seconds) {
    var buttons = $("input[type=submit]").add("button").not(".navbar-toggle");
    buttons.each(function(i, button) {
        button = $(button);
        var org_text = button.text();
        if(!org_text) org_text = button.val();

        button
            .prop("disabled", true)
            .text(seconds)
            .val(seconds);

        var i = setInterval(function() {
            seconds -= 1;
            if(seconds <= 0) {
                clearInterval(i);
                button
                    .prop("disabled", false)
                    .text(org_text)
                    .val(org_text);
            } else {
                button.text(seconds).val(seconds);
            }
        }, 1000);

        window.disableButtonTimer = function() {
            clearInterval(i);
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: `but i am trying` - how are you trying this - can't tell what's wrong with code you don't post

Comment: '<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 // iframe
 $('.adbit-display-ad').iframeTracker({
  blurCallback: function(){
   $('<div class="consoleDebug">').html('<input type="submit" id="get" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Get!">').appendTo('#consoleDebug').delay(3000).fadeIn(1000);
  }
 });
});
</script>'